# How to call async method from MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, async-await

So I wrote a quick `async` method to get some data into a `DataTable` from an Oracle db.  How am I suppose to call this from `MainWindow()` without blocking UI thread?  The `async`/`wait` model doesn't really make much sense there.

```
    async Task<DataTable> AccessOracleAsync()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(@"SELECT * FROM myTbl", conn))
        {
            await conn.OpenAsync();
            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);                        
            }

        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Without seeing your constructor, it's hard to say what might "make sense" there. But you have at least a couple of options here.

**Option #1:** put the call in the constructor.

In this case, you can't make the method `async`, and you most certainly don't want your continuation to do anything that needs to be done before the constructor returns. But you can still do effectively what C# would have done for you in an `async` method:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AccessOracleAsync().ContinueWith(task => { /* do some other stuff */ },
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

That will execute the continuation on the UI thread, as if you had written `await AccessOracleAsync(); /* do some other stuff */`. Add exception handling in the continuation method as necessary (i.e. inspect the `task` object and handle appropriately).

**Option #2:** put the call somewhere else.

It has been suggested to use the `Loaded` event, which you can do. That might look something like this:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await AccessOracleAsync();

    // do some other stuff
}
```

Note that if the latter seems appropriate, IMHO it's preferable. It lets the C# compiler do the heavy-lifting for you, including dealing with exceptions (you can just wrap the call in `try`/`catch` and everything "just works").

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a handler for the `Laoded` event, marking it as `async` and call your `AccessOracleAsync` method from there.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done this and boy was it a struggle! you can't just call your method as suggested in the other answer as the calling method or constructor will end and the task will be lost.

I did two things

1: bind the window loaded event rather than doing it in the constructor

2: you MUST call Task.Run if you want to run in a background process, regardless of whether your method is async or not

eg

```
    public async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(()=>this.AccessOracleAsync().ContinueWith(function to deal with results));
    }
```

furthermore, if you need to get back to the foreground thread to update the UI with your results you will want to enable your collection for thread safety

```
    public MainVM()
    {
        this.results= new ObservableCollection<resultType>();
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(results, _itemsLock);
    }
    private static object _itemsLock = new object();
    public ObservableCollection<resultType> results{ get; set; }
```